# jQuery insertAfter doesn't work in some situations

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I want to add a hidden input after some element.
I am using this code:

```
$("<input type="text">").insertAfter(".addProduct");
```

It doesn't work. But if I replace  to  it works.

```
$("<span>ddd</span>").insertAfter(".addProduct");
```

It works.
Help me.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you create this script in php, use this:

```
$("<input type=\"text\">").insertAfter(".addProduct");
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use single quotes:

```
$('<input type="text" />').insertAfter('.addProduct');
```

Comment: @Alexander.Plutov Yes it does. However, if you're generating it by means of PHP or the like, the quoting may collapse with the one used by PHP.

Comment: Then either the `.addProduct` element you expect does not exist or is hidden or the problem lies somewhere else.